# How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Java EE web application

Tags: jakarta-ee

Let's say I am currently in Singapore and I want to retrieve the addresses of the shops from a database and wanna show shop names (around the current location) to users.
Which API should I use ?

PS. My application is Java EE with Struts and the Spring frame work.

Comment: A little unclear exactly what it is you're trying to do. If you're running a J2EE application, then it's a server-side application; how does that fit with your question about getting current GPS location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

It helped me exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Maps API:

http://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: I want to show only the shop lists  according to the client's current geographical location . Thanks in advance , Isaac :)

Comment: OK. So your J2EE application has to receive the user's location somehow (using request parameters, for example), then use the Google Maps API to retrieve a list of business, and return them to the client.

Comment: The user's device (a smartphone? a laptop?) will have to provide you with the user's current location. You can't invoke functionality on the server side, asking for the client side's physical location... at least not with J2EE technology.

Comment: You're probably going to have much more luck rephrasing your question, and asking how (using client-side technologies for mobile platforms) is it possible to submit GPS coordinates as a part of an HTTP request to the server.